# Wrap divs from one class to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with a calendar with the following markup: http://jsfiddle.net/PHznZ/

Using jQuery, how can I wrap each week (Sunday `.start-week` through Saturday `.end-week`) with a containing element called `.full-week`? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/PHznZ/1/

Here's the targeted HTML code:

```
<div id="calendar">
    <article class="day start-week">
        <span class="dayname">Sunday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Monday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Tuesday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Wednesday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Thursday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Friday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day end-week">
        <span class="dayname">Saturday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day start-week">
        <span class="dayname">Sunday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Monday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Tuesday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Wednesday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Thursday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Friday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day end-week">
        <span class="dayname">Saturday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day start-week">
        <span class="dayname">Sunday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Monday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Tuesday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Wednesday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Thursday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Friday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day end-week">
        <span class="dayname">Saturday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day start-week">
        <span class="dayname">Sunday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Monday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Tuesday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Wednesday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Thursday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day">
        <span class="dayname">Friday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
    <article class="day end-week">
        <span class="dayname">Saturday</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code here instead of only providing it on another website.

Comment: If you don't post your code here, it's "too localized" and is less able to help future readers when the links become unavailable. Since you don't seem to want to do the work yourself, I'll do it for you this time. But please understand that questions on StackOverflow are not just about the asker, but are meant to benefit the entire community for years to come.

Comment: Gotcha. Didn't think of it in that way. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
​$(".start-week").each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.end-week + *').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="full-week">');
});​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/7mnAc/)</kbd>

```
$(".start-week").nextUntil('[class*="end-week"]').wrapAll('<div class="full-week">');
```

---

I'm very late to answer :)

Shorter and Faster Version of [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/913761/roman) answer .

Comment: Uhm... doesn't really work. Your fiddle has the `.fullweek` divs already in the starting HTML and you're not linking to jQuery (so nothing happens [except some errors in the console]). Once linked to jQuery and corrected the HTML, your fiddle looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/og9ogfge/1/